# Difference between values of three columns from two tables

Tags: jquery, sql, sqlite

I have two files with three columns each.

`data1.txt`: https://pastebin.com/ezVr6KPi

```
# P (Gpa)       G / F. unit  (a.u.)     T (K)
-4.4119598462100 -941.5590019525371 10.0000000000000
-4.4115664473800 -941.5589977004460 30.1000000000000
-4.4084485632200 -941.5589688036446 50.2000000000000
-4.3989188608700 -941.5588816009147 70.3000000000000
...
```

`data2.txt`: https://pastebin.com/veqBi8Er

```
# P (Gpa)       G / F. unit  (a.u.)     T (K)
7.5789845745700 -941.3858364185293 10.0000000000000
7.5936983738200 -941.3856461092793 30.1000000000000
7.6147899594200 -941.3853929461748 50.2000000000000
7.6413267974900 -941.3851062350891 70.3000000000000
...
```

I have created 2 tables and named the columns in a `tables.sql` script:

```
.headers on

CREATE TABLE C_I("P1" TEXT, "G1" TEXT, "T1" TEXT);
CREATE TABLE C_II("P2" TEXT, "G2" TEXT, "T2" TEXT);
```

I import the data:

```
.separator " "

.import './data1.txt'  C_I
.import './data2.txt'  C_II
```

And then I remove the native header from the files, just to refer better to the column names given above:

```
select T1 from C_I LIMIT 3;
select P1 from C_I LIMIT 3;
select G1 from C_I LIMIT 3;

DELETE FROM C_I WHERE T1 == '(Gpa)';
DELETE FROM C_I WHERE P1 == '#';
DELETE FROM C_I WHERE G1 == 'P';

DELETE FROM C_II WHERE T2 == '(Gpa)';
DELETE FROM C_II WHERE P2 == '#';
DELETE FROM C_II WHERE G2 == 'P';

select * from C_I LIMIT 3;
select * from C_II LIMIT 3;
```

I am trying to obtain the values of `P1`, `G1`, `T1`, `P2`, `G2`, `T2` for which:

`P1 = P2` (within a threshold) `AND` `T1 = T2` (within a threshold) `AND` `G1 = G2` (within a threshold).

For this I do:

**Update:**

**OPTION 1:**

```
SELECT * FROM   C_I l1,  C_II l2
WHERE
    ABS(l1.P1-l2.P2) < 0.005
    AND
    ABS(l1.T1-l2.T2) < 20.0
    AND
    ABS(l1.G1-l2.G2) < 0.005
```

This prints the following error:

```
Error: incomplete SQL: SELECT * FROM   C_I l1,  C_II l2 
WHERE 
    ABS(l1.P1-l2.P2) < 0.005
    AND
    ABS(l1.T1-l2.T2) < 20.0
    AND
    ABS(l1.G1-l2.G2) < 0.005
```

**OPTION 2:** Adding `;`

```
SELECT * FROM   C_I l1,  C_II l2;
WHERE
    ABS(l1.P1-l2.P2) < 0.005
    AND
    ABS(l1.T1-l2.T2) < 20.0
    AND
    ABS(l1.G1-l2.G2) < 0.005
```

In this case the entire two tables appear through terminal,
and apparently this code has had no effect. Even if I set the threshold to `0.0` in those three statements, it happens the same (If the threshold was `0.0` no output would be expected).

**OPTION 3:** As @Myonara suggested, adding `;` here:

```
SELECT P, G, T FROM   C_I l1 ,  C_II  l2
WHERE
    ABS(l1.P1-l2.P2) < 0.005;
    AND
    ABS(l1.T1-l2.T2) < 20.0
    AND
    ABS(l1.G-l2.G2) < 0.005
```

produces this error:

```
Error: incomplete SQL: AND
    ABS(l1.T1-l2.T2) < 20.0
    AND
    ABS(l1.G1-l2.G2) < 0.005
```

Thus, something I cannot understand is not working

I would appreciate if you could help me.

**Complete script:** `tables.sql` :

I am running it as: `sqlite3 < tables.sql`  :

```
.headers on

CREATE TABLE C_I("P1" TEXT, "G1" TEXT, "T1" TEXT);
CREATE TABLE C_II("P2" TEXT, "G2" TEXT, "T2" TEXT);

.separator " "

.import './data1.txt'  C_I
.import './data2.txt'  C_II


select T1 from C_I LIMIT 3;
select P1 from C_I LIMIT 3;
select G1 from C_I LIMIT 3;


DELETE FROM C_I WHERE T1 == '(Gpa)';
DELETE FROM C_I WHERE P1 == '#';
DELETE FROM C_I WHERE G1 == 'P';

DELETE FROM C_II WHERE T2 == '(Gpa)';
DELETE FROM C_II WHERE P2 == '#';
DELETE FROM C_II WHERE G2 == 'P';


select * from C_I LIMIT 3;
select * from C_II LIMIT 3;


SELECT * FROM   C_I l1,  C_II l2;
WHERE
    ABS(l1.P1-l2.P2) < 0.005
    AND
    ABS(l1.T1-l2.T2) < 20.0
    AND
    ABS(l1.G1-l2.G2) < 0.005
```

Comment: you may need semicolon at the last query

Comment: @Ali Yes, I have added the `;` at the last query, and the result is that the entire 2 tables appear through terminal. Even if I set the tolerance to `0.0` in the three cases, it happens the same -  see update

Comment: why did you put `;` in this query `SELECT * FROM   C_I l1,  C_II l2;` and then continue with `WHERE` clause? are they one query?

Comment: @Ikrom with a good spot. The semicolon would be terminating the select statement, so you may be asking for a cross join at this point, ignoring the where conditions.

Comment: @Ikrom Thanks for your comment. Please see updated post, where I analyse the effect of adding or not the `;`

Comment: @Ali  I have analyzed the effect of adding or not the `;` - please see updated post

Comment: In the first OPTION1 do the `;` at the end of the `SELECT` meaning after the `< 0.005`.

Comment: @Myonara Thanks for your comment, but that seems not to work also - see updated option 3

Comment: @DavidC. So, now it's more clear. Do you need `P1=P2` ... OR `(P1-P2) < treshold ...` ? Do you have the same number of rows in both tables?

Comment: @Ikrom Thanks for your comment. As you can see from the links to the tables, they have different number of rows: `401` rows in `C_II` and `1701` rows in `C_I`. I would need `<`, as stated in the post.

Comment: @DavidC. So, if there are diff count of rows in tables then how to operate if the process came to the rows 402? In example it is like this: .... `l1.P1.row_402 (which is already finished) - l2.P2.row_402` Need to stop here? And 2nd: for Selecting row all 3 conditions in WHERE clause must match, right?

Comment: @Ikrom Thanks for your comment. Answer to 1st: `Any row from l1` has to be compared with `any row from l2`. The comparison has not to be made "pair-wise-in-rows", i.e.`row 1 from l1` to be compared with `row 1 from l2`. Instead, I'm looking for `row 1 from l1` to be compared with `any row from l2` (the vice-versa statement, i.e., `row 1 from l2` to be compared with `any row from l1` would lead to the same result). Answer to 2nd: Yes, all 3 conditions in WHERE clause must match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one as only this is the complete sql syntax for SELECT, which you need:

```
SELECT P, G, T FROM   C_I l1 ,  C_II  l2
WHERE
    ABS(l1.P-l2.P) < 0.005
    AND
    ABS(l1.T-l2.T) < 20.0
    AND
    ABS(l1.G-l2.G) < 0.005;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I run the code, I receive this message:`expected 3 columns but found 22 - extras ignored` Do you know why this is happening ?

Comment: No, after googling "extra ignored sqilite" without the " I get some hints to the import of the csv files, maybe that helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments, this is the right script for you:

`SELECT l1.p1, l2.p2, l1.t1, l2.t2, l1.g1, l2.g2   FROM C_I l1,  C_II l2
WHERE
    ABS(l1.P1-l2.P2) < 0.005
    AND
    ABS(l1.T1-l2.T2) < 20.0
    AND
    ABS(l1.G1-l2.G2) < 0.005;`

I will explain what does do this script:
 1. `SELECT l1.p1, l2.p2, l1.t1, l2.t2, l1.g1, l2.g2   FROM C_I l1,  C_II l2` - here it's just creating a Cartesian product (also called as Cross Join) as you want. It means that it will provide a table with 680.000 row (400 rows * 1700 rows = 680.000 rows), `for each record from table C_I` will be provided `1700 records from table C_II`;
 2. in `WHERE` clause it will do calculations and from the script, you have `only one (1) match` for all `your 3 conditions` there;
 3. For example, only for this condition `ABS(l1.P1-l2.P2) < 0.005` you have `91 matches`, if you apply the 2nd one then only 1 match;

Hope it will help you!